# Payout vs withdrawal

Tags: terminology

I have a website where the users have an amount of money on their account and they can ask for it to be paid... What is the best way to call this action?

Also, for example, the admin can "cancel the pending withdrawal request" or "cancel the pending payout request"?

Comment: You need more context here. *[Users] can ask for it to be paid*... to whom? To themselves? To you? To a third party? All these things are different actions.

Comment: @CharlE Ideally, the completed version would be "[Users] can ask for it to be paid to John Clifford."

Comment: @JohnClifford  - naturally. But teasing that detail out is the thrust of my comment.

Comment: It's paid to a PayPal (or Paxum, Payoneer, Webmoney, wire transfer ecc.) account, that they have set in their profile page. Usually it belongs to themselves... It's a credit that they have earned for providing some services to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the dictionary definitions:

> **Payout** *noun*
> A large payment of money, especially as compensation or a dividend: *an insurance payout*
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/payout)
>
> **Withdrawal** *count noun*
> 1.1 An act of taking money out of an account.
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/withdrawal)

The word *payout* is normally used in the sense of someone *else* paying you for some reason, whether that reason is legal, contractual or ethical, etc.

In your context, the word **withdrawal** is more suitable - the account holder *withdraws* funds and may want to cancel a pending *withdrawal request*.

Here's a [PayPal page](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Adding-and-withdrawing-money/How-Do-I-Cancel-A-Withdrawal/td-p/454443?profile.language=en-gb) that uses the phrase "cancel a withdrawal", and here's one regarding the [cancellation of a withdrawal that is still pending](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Adding-and-withdrawing-money/Can-i-cancel-the-withdrawal-which-is-still-pending/td-p/777827).